# How do I add links to hard-coded images in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a website and using the regular theme Home page and not creating a static page. The theme (Business Elite) has a Contact Us section near the bottom of the page. The url I am working on is http://dlecpa1.com  . The theme does not allow me to change the three images that are in the Contact Us section so they would have links.

I did figure out how to change the first image text line to read "CALL US" by changing it in the css under inc-front-front-function php, but that does not help me with adding links to the second and third images (circle_bg2 and circle_bg3).

I know I can't add links using css, so I tried my hand using javascript but I got lost trying. I know that I need to add js and html for the links to work but I have no clue as to how I can do this. I don't know if this helps, but this is what is in the css I found.

```
<!-- TOP PART -->
        <ul class="cont_us_top container">
          <?php if ($contact_us_name) { ?>
            <!--name-->
            <li>
              <div class="circle" id="circle_bg1"></div>
              <div><p class="cont_title"> <?php echo __('CALL US', "business-elite"); ?> </p>
                <p class="cont_text"> <?php echo $contact_us_name; ?> </p></div>
            </li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($contact_us_address) { ?>
            <!--address-->
            <li>
              <div class="circle" id="circle_bg2"></div>
              <div><p class="cont_title"> <?php echo __('ADDRESS', "business-elite"); ?> </p>
                <p class="cont_text"> <?php echo $contact_us_address; ?> </p></div>
            </li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($contact_us_mail && $contact_us_showmail) { ?>
            <!--mail-->
            <li>
              <div class="circle" id="circle_bg3"></div>
              <div><p class="cont_title"> <?php echo __('EMAIL', "business-elite"); ?> </p>
                <p class="cont_text"> <?php echo $contact_us_mail; ?> </p></div>
            </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>

        <div class="right_home right_home_center">
          <?php self::social_icons(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go into your CSS and look for the #circle_bg1 ID, and then change the background image to one that you want:

```
#circle_bg1 {
    background: url(images/yournewimagelink.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
```

The 3 circle classes are located in your style.css doc, starting on line number 1979.

Comment: Thank you, I did find that before and changed the image to an image that I uploaded into my wordpress library that had a custom url added to it. It did change the image but it did not recognize the image having a link. As I stated, I need links for 2nd and 3rd images. I need to add links and not change the images.